# Segmentation fault when destructing a derived std::basic_ostream

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, libc++

I am deriving from `std::basic_ostream` because I need to change the way underlying file buffer is created. (I need a unique filename that I can query so the file can be deleted when it is closed; i.e., can't use `std::tmpnam` or `std::tmpfile`.) I've made an attempt at this (see below), but I get a segmentation fault at destruction.

**What is causing the segmentation fault?** It seems that either I'm not allocating memory for the file buffer, or I'm deleting it twice.

```cpp
// Compile with
//      clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp  -o tmpFile
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <streambuf>

using namespace std;

template< class charT, class traits=char_traits<charT> >
class FILE_streambuf : public std::basic_streambuf<charT, traits> {
public:
    FILE_streambuf(std::string& filename)
    {
      filename = "chicken";
      buffer_ = fopen(filename.c_str(), "wx");

    }

    virtual ~FILE_streambuf(){
        fclose(this->buffer_);
    }
    FILE* buffer_;
};

template< class charT, class traits=char_traits<charT> >
class tmp_ofstream : public basic_ostream<charT, traits>{
public:
    tmp_ofstream()
    : filename_("")
    {
        try{
            this->rdbuf(new FILE_streambuf<charT, traits>(filename_));
        } catch (const std::exception& e){
            throw e;
        }
    }

    ~tmp_ofstream(){
        delete this->rdbuf();
        remove( filename_.c_str() );
    }
    std::string filename() { return this->filename_; };
    std::string filename_;
};

int main(){

    tmp_ofstream<char> tmpStream;
    cout << "tmpStream has filename: " << tmpStream.filename();

    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you should *never* `free()` what you `new`. `new` -> `delete`, `malloc` -> `free`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I change the `free` to `delete` I still get the same segmentation fault. :(

Comment: The provided source code doesn't generate the described error, could you give more details ?

Comment: @J.Piquard I ran this again and got this: `$ if clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ main2.cpp  -o tmpFile; then ./tmpFile; fi
tmpStream has filename: chicken
-----------------------------------------
Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: You're certain `fopen` returns a non-null value?

Comment: @G.M. Yes, see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)

Comment: Why are you calling `remove( filename_.c_str() );` in the `~tmp_ofstream()` ?

Comment: `std::basic_ostream` is not supposed to have a default constructor. It's not clear how  your program even compiles. Making it `tmp_ofstream() : filename_(""), basic_ostream<charT, traits>(nullptr)` [seems to work for me](http://rextester.com/PPROA4705)

Comment: In your tmp_ofstream constructor, you can call the ostream constructor (with your FILE_streambuf*) in an initialization list. rdbuf() shouldn't take any parameters.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "*std::basic_ostream is not supposed to have a default constructor"* `libc++` [does provide a protected default constructor](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/ostream) (see the bottom of the class declaration).

Comment: @J.Piquard I want the file to be deleted from the file system when the object is deconstructed. That's why I need to write these classes.

Comment: @Leon Well, it's a non-standard extension. Apparently, it requires some special care (because it, and I quote, "intentially[sic] does not initialize") when used - probably an explicit call to `init()` - care that the OP's code is not exercising.

Answer (score 0):

As [Igor Tandetnik has noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511599/segmentation-fault-when-destructing-a-derived-stdbasic-ostream?noredirect=1#comment68267434_40511599) the code implicitly calls the default constructor of `std::basic_ostream` which is not supposed to exist. The code compiles with libc++ because [the latter provides](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/ostream) such a (protected) default constructor as an extension:

> ```
> basic_ostream() {}  // extension, intentially does not initialize
> ```

The problem disappears if the constructor of `tmp_ofstream` calls a standard-approved constructor of `std::basic_ostream`:

```
tmp_ofstream()
: basic_ostream<charT, traits>(0) // Sic!
, filename_("")
{
    try{
        this->rdbuf(new FILE_streambuf<charT, traits>(filename_));
    } catch (const std::exception& e){
        throw e;
    }
}
```